# Group by with sum of all rows in mysql select query

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to get all record sum with the group by function.
here is the e.x. which I have using

Query -

```
SELECT CONCAT(round(IF(avg(calories), avg(calories), 0), 2), "kcal") as avg, CONCAT(round(IF(SUM(calories), SUM(calories), 0), 2), "kcal") as total_calories
FROM `tbl_mst`
WHERE `date` BETWEEN "2021-01-26" AND "2021-02-10"
AND `user_id` = '23'
AND `calories` != '0'
GROUP BY `date`
```

OUTPUT -

```
|     avg     | total_calories  |
| ----------  | --------------  |
| 105.00kcal  | 105.00kcal      |
| 172.50kcal  | 345.00kcal      |
| 100.00kcal  | 100.00kcal      |
| 221.38kcal  | 1771.00kcal     |
| 1.00kcal    | 1.00kcal        |
| 396.00kcal  | 396.00kcal      |
| 96.28kcal   | 385.10kcal      |
| 297.20kcal  | 1486.00kcal     |
```

But, I want to SUM and avg of all the above rows in single row.
I want to below output -

```
|     avg     | total_calories  |
| ----------  | --------------  |
| 573.64kcal  | 4589.10kcal     |
```

Comment: Skip the GROUP BY.

Comment: .. or use GROUP BY .. WITH ROLLUP.

Comment: Do you want the average of the total, or the sum of those averages?

Comment: @jarlh If I have to skip GROUP BY then avg is not properly calculate, cause in a single date there are multiple entries in the table.

Comment: @Charlieface, yes I want to average of the total.

Comment: Then remove the `GROUP BY` line

Comment: @Charlieface, If I have to remove `GROUP BY` then avg is not calculate properly, cause in a single date there are multiple entries in the table.

Comment: So you actually **do** want the average of the averages? Then put the whole thing in a derived table and `AVG` again that result. Or use `WITH ROLLUP` if your DBMS supports that.

Comment: Please see [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Answer (score 0):

You can use your query as subquery to achieve your desired result.

```
select avg(total_calories)avg,sum(total_calories)total_calories from(
SELECT CONCAT(round(IF(avg(calories), avg(calories), 0), 2), "kcal") as avg, CONCAT(round(IF(SUM(calories), SUM(calories), 0), 2), "kcal") as total_calories
FROM `tbl_mst`
WHERE `date` BETWEEN "2021-01-26" AND "2021-02-10"
AND `user_id` = '23'
AND `calories` != '0'
GROUP BY `date`) t
```

Please share table structure and sample data for better solution.